# ps command with u option only shows user processes

Tags: process

As a non-root user, when I run `top` or `ps aux`, I only see processes with my user name.

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mahmood 31398  0.1  0.0 117152  3948 pts/10   Ss   19:27   0:00 -bash
mahmood 32468  0.0  0.0 148964  1872 pts/10   R+   19:31   0:00 ps aux
$
```

How can I fix that in a way to show all processes?

Comment: Are you on Linux with `hidepid` set?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: See how your /proc is mounted, more info e.g. https://linux-audit.com/linux-system-hardening-adding-hidepid-to-proc/ or when you type sth like "hidepid linux" into Google.

Comment: What does `mount | grep hidepid` return?

Comment: @A.Danischewski: It says `proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=2)`